# PowerShell how to unsplat

Tags: powershell

I know how to use splatting to pass parameters to a cmdlet.

How would I write a cmdlet to "unsplat"?  I want to get all the parameters passed to my function as a hashtable.

For example:

```
function Test-Unsplat
{
    [cmdletbinding()]

    param(
        $ParamA,
        $ParamB
    )

    # WHAT TO DO HERE TO GET @{ParamA = '...', ParamB = '...'}
}
```

Comment: What problem does it solve?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, so I can bundle up all the parameters and splat them to another cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with

```
Get-Help about_Splatting
```

The answer I was looking for is $PSBoundParameters.